# How to use promoted variables in Workshop modules while opening them in Carbon workspaces?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

We have a Workshop module that is often accessed by users in two different ways:

- using browser to access a Carbon workspace, then the Workshop module
- using links from notifications/emails about performed actions that is sent via ontology action notification

The most useful initial layout (which is controlled via a boolean variable, currently linked to a tickbox widget in the module) depends on the way a user accesses this module.

We see functionality that allows us to generate a url with promoted variables, thus allowing us to change the defualt state of this boolean variable via url, however from initial testing, promoted variables do not work when accessing module via a Carbon workspace (i.e. despite adding the url parameter, it is truncated and upon loading the variable is in its default state). If that is the case, when setting up action notification we cannot point to Carbon workspace.

Is there a way to use promoted variables if we want to open this module in a Carbon workspace? Alternatively, is there a way to achieve different layouts that would change depending on where the module is being accessed from without using promoted variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Here's how you pass the promoted variable value to the workshop module inside the carbon workspace.

1. Configure the Carbon workspace using the YAML editor
2. In the section where you include the module you're referring to, change the YAML from what you have to something that looks like the config below (see the [docs for what I referred to example](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/carbon/code-reference/#custom-section-with-module-item---workshop-module-with-promoted-variables)).
3. In the YAML, pass in your boolean as a string, just like I have below. The name of my promoted variable in this example is `isChecked`

In the browser's URL bar you should see this:
[image]

**Config:**

```
displayMetadata:
  title: Promoted Var Workspace
  description: null
  enableDarkMode: null
  headerMenuOptions: null
  isAcademyShown: false
  isHelpShown: false
  isDocumentationShown: false
  isNotificationsDropdownShown: true
  isUserProfileShown: true
versionMetadata:
  description: Initial version
discoverableModules:
  - ri.workshop.main.module.<the-module-your-question-is-about>
configuration:
  moduleShortcuts:
    primary: []
    secondary: []
  homePage:
    type: internalHomePage
    internalHomePage:
      logo: null
      welcomeText: null
      welcomeTextWithMarkdown: null
      shouldHideSearchBar: null
      searchBarPlaceholder: null
      defaultObjectTypesFilter: null
      columns:
        - sections:
            - title: Module with promoted var
              description: null
              displayAs: null
              contents:
                type: custom
                custom:
                  items:
                    - type: module
                      module:
                        displayMetadata:
                          title: null
                          description: null
                          icon: null
                          thumbnail: null
                        moduleRid: >-
                          ri.workshop.main.module.<the-module-your-question-is-about>
                        parameterValues:
                          variable.isChecked:
                            type: string
                            string:
                              string: 'true'
        - sections:
            - title: null
              description: null
              displayAs: null
              contents:
                type: objectTypes
                objectTypes:
                  objectTypes: null
        - sections:
            - title: null
              description: null
              displayAs: null
              contents:
                type: savedExplorations
                savedExplorations: {}
  parameters: []
  parametersDisplayMetadata: null
  enablement:
    navigationOutOfCarbonDisabled: false
    moduleBlockList: []
targetDeviceTypes: []
```

And here's what it looks like:
[image: gif of opening app from workspace with url param]

Comment: Thank you. Took me some time to mark this as correct answer, as my original problem persists. This is indeed the way to use promoted variables within Carbon workspace, and I've made use of it. However, the original problem requires to set a value to a Checkbox widget backed boolean variable. This solution works reloading the page with the same parameters or directing to the URL. Opening from workspace homepage, I see error in console: `Uncaught exception while computing variable Error: Expected value to be of type 'boolean'. But it was not. Actual value is 'false'`. Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I see. I wonder if maybe I'm not fully understanding what you're trying to do. I'm unable to repro that error. I added a gif to my answer -- is that a correct representation of what you're after? If yes, I would double-check your yaml, making sure you're using single quotes where required, etc. I realize that's probably not a very satisfying comment.

Comment: That looks about what I am expecting. I use this boolean to filter out an object set upon module loading, but even the checkbox doesn't reflect the value passed in the yaml config (if it's ticked by default, setting it to 'false' in yaml doesn't result in unticked box when going via Carbon workspace, only directly via URL). I have checked the config and it looks the same as other promoted variables I used in this module. I might try creating an Issue directly in the platform, since it seems to work fine on your end. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A Carbon can utilize promoted Workshop variables in one of two ways: 1) using the Carbon configuration pane's built-in options, or 2) by replacing the built-in options with a Workshop.

Option 1) Add a Workshop resource to the Carbon.  When adding the Workshop, name a parameter "variable.[insert promoted id]", and set it's value.  For example: parameter: variable.source.  Value: carbon.  This should then open the Workshop with "carbon" passed as a value to the promoted variable.  Note: In Workshop, the variable name doesn't matter, just the promoted ID, and the promoted ID in Workshop should not include "variable.".

Option 2) In an embedded Workshop, use events (i.e. button events) to pass a variable to another Workshop.  The resource list can be used, but only if each resource also uses an event: Open Workshop resource (same Workshop) and then select inputs for promoted variables.